# Calculating a point based on an existing point, the angle and distance.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider the following image:

[image: Lines with arrow heads]

I have two arbitrary points (p1 and p2) on which a line is drawn. I want to calculate it's mid-point and draw directional arrows going from p1 towards p2.

I think I have the logic right but am probably missing something in the implementation. I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible to just represent the math:

```
function GetArrowHeadLines (Point p1, Point p2) // Returns two lines.
{
    length = Sqrt(Power(p1.X - p2.X, 2) + Power(p1.Y - p2.Y, 2));
    size = length * 0.1; // The size of the arrow head.
    gradient = ((p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X));
    Point midPoint = new Point((p2.X + p1.X) / 2, (p2.Y + p1.Y) / 2);

    // Calculate angle in radians from gradient.
    // The Atan2 function takes (y, x) instead of (x, y) on my platform. This is not an error.
    angle = (float) Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X);

    Point pointArrowHead1 = new Point();
    Point pointArrowHead2 = new Point();

    // Use circle formula to calculate pointArrowHead1.
    pointArrowHead1.X = midPoint.X + ((float) Cos(angle + (45 * Pi / 180D)) * size));
    pointArrowHead1.Y = midPoint.Y + ((float) Sin(angle + (45 * Pi / 180D)) * size));

    // Use circle formula to calculate pointArrowHead2.
    pointArrowHead2.X = midPoint.X + ((float) Cos(angle - (45 * Pi / 180D)) * size));
    pointArrowHead2.Y = midPoint.Y + ((float) Sin(angle - (45 * Pi / 180D)) * size));

    Line line1 = new Line(midPoint, pointArrowHead1);
    Line line2 = new Line(midPoint, pointArrowHead2);

    return line1, line2;
}
```

**UPDATE:** After using the Atan2 function to get the angle in radians, here is the output on some random lines:

[image: Using Atan2]

Comment: Why does a function that "returns two lines" called `GetPoints()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your midpoint is fine.  For the angle, you might want to look at the [Atan2 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) if your system provides it.  It takes care of figuring out the quadrant ambiguity for you.  It also avoids the divide by zero if the line is vertical.  I don't understand the negative inverse of gradient (which gives the slope of a perpendicular line) or the division by $100F$ (whatever that is).

Comment: Thanks. the negative inverse of the gradient is just left-over code from experimenting. Will update. The division 100 along with the following line is an attempt to convert the gradient to an angle in radians.

Comment: The Atan2 function is available on my platform as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Math.Atan2);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). I am not sure how to interpret it since it takes two parameters (x and y). Since I want to convert gradient into an angle, which point should I be passing in here?

Comment: You should put your p2.X-p1.X in for x and similarly for y.  It gives the angle of the line with the direction without calculating the gradient.

Comment: Thank you. I should have figured that based on your answer. Have updated the code and attached an image displaying current results. It appears there may also be something wrong with the attempt to add and subtract 45 degrees to get both arrow heads. I am assuming this is not a quadrant issue since Atan2 takes care of that.

Comment: there was an error in the image I uploaded previously (where gradient > 0). Have updated it with a correct one.